# Do I need locks to write into socket using the same application twice and simultaneously?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

As you know, writing into a shared memory between different threads needs locks (Mutex, Semaphores ...).

My C++ program is in charge of filling up `SO_SNDBUF` and writing data into socket (as a part of  throttling the network).

Here you could find the relevant part of code:

```
getsockopt(sendsockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sndBufferSize, &sbsLen);
...
write(sendsockfd,buffer,sndBufferSize);
```

When I run this program simultaneously twice on the same pc (i.e. it becomes two different applications with two different sockets), what can I say about the writing buffer, is it considered as a shared memory `tcp_wmem`? Thus, shall I use locks for writing?

P.S. I am using blocking mode.

Comment: It's not clear: what are the two programs doing?  Are they sharing one socket (unlikely but possible on Unix)?  What does it mean "fulling up SO_SNDBUF"?  I guess you mean you're sending data from two different processes to two different sockets?

Comment: Would you please notify me if my questions are unclear, because I asked yesterday a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683393/could-i-force-the-socket-to-use-wmem-max-instead-of-wmem-default-in-c and I didn't get any answer neither a comment.

Comment: What kind of socket is it?  TCP?  Unix?  UDP?  Raw?

Comment: Dear @JeremyFriesner, it's TCP i am trying to fill up tcp_wmem.

Comment: @Moi: It would be bad to write to the same TCP socket unsynchronized, because data from the different threads could end up interleaved, giving the receiver no hope of sorting it out again.  With datagram sockets, at least the writes from independent threads would go out as separate units.  Luckily you have separate sockets.

Comment: @BenVoigt, It's actually two separate sockets :) because I am running the same application twice separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should not use locks for writing in this case.  Think about it: how would two programs written by two different companies work on the same machine if they needed to take locks before writing to independent sockets?

Even writing to two separate sockets in the same program does not require locking.

Comment: You are right, my question is about filling up writing buffers of the socket. Then, how could both fill up until tcp_wmem?

Comment: The sockets are independent.  The buffers for one socket have nothing to do with the other.

Comment: Ok, would you please explain more about what would happen to tcp_wmem in very high rates (i.e. wmem_max)?

Comment: When a buffer fills up, sending will block.  That is, the sending program will "hang" until the buffer drains somewhat.